# How to exclude javascript dependencies using the sbt-scalajs plugin in a scalajs-react project?

Tags: sbt, scala.js, scalajs-react

How to exclude scalajs dependencies using sbt-scalajs plugin ?

I'm trying to import the following library

```
"org.webjars.bower" % "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker" % "0.0.14" / "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"
```

But this library is downloading other dependencies ("react" and "react-bootstrap") which are already in my project and I'm getting version clashes.

I've tried using the exclude function

```
"org.webjars.bower" % "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker" % "0.0.14" exclude ("org.webjars.bower", "react")
```

but this does not allow me to append / "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" to the command.

The exception I get is:

```
org.scalajs.core.tools.classpath.JSLibResolveException: Some references to JS libraries could not be resolved:
- Ambiguous reference to a JS library: react-bootstrap.js
  Possible paths found on the classpath:
  - META-INF/resources/webjars/react-bootstrap/0.16.1/react-bootstrap.js
  - META-INF/resources/webjars/react-bootstrap/0.23.7/react-bootstrap.js
  originating from: adminJS:compile

    at org.scalajs.core.tools.classpath.PartialClasspath.resolveAllResourceNames(PartialClasspath.scala:137)
    at org.scalajs.core.tools.classpath.PartialClasspath.resolveDependencies(PartialClasspath.scala:80)
    at org.scalajs.core.tools.classpath.PartialClasspath.resolve(PartialClasspath.scala:64)
    at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$11.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:140)
    at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$11.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:137)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exclude` is a feature of sbt's `libraryDependencies`, and is not replicated in `jsDependencies`. So you can't declare an `exclude` directly in you `jsDependencies`. However, since `jsDependencies` builds on top of `libraryDependencies`, you can achieve what you want by combining both, with a little bit of duplicate code:

```
libraryDependencies +=
  "org.webjars.bower" % "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker" % "0.0.14" exclude ("org.webjars.bower", "react")
jsDependencies +=
  "org.webjars.bower" % "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker" % "0.0.14" / "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"
```